# Cross validation in r with categoical variable

Tags: r, cross-validation

While I was trying to use cross-validation technique in R, I got this error which says

> Warning in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...): cannnot compute class probabilities for regression

> Warning in nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo, :
> There were missing values in resampled performance measures.

what am I supposed to do?

Comment: It is not an error, but a warning message

Comment: As the warning says, do you have missing values in your data?

Comment: what am i supposed to do? shall i make any changes ? add or subtract data from the train set?

Comment: Impossible to answer unless you share a minimal reproducible example of your data: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example